# How do I link a folder on my local drive to SharePoint without actually uploading all of its contents?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to link a folder in my local drive to SharePoint. However, I don't want to upload all of its contents on it since it's a ridiculously large folder. I only want to link that folder and all of its sub-folders on SharePoint for navigation, and if someone attempts to open a file inside that folder, it would open it on Windows Explorer.

Comment: it wouldn't be your local drive, you'd want it at least on a server...the link on the path would be file://servername/path_to_files/filename

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a simple directory listing, then I suggest you add the folder (has to be on a server), to IIS (Internet Information Services), as a pseudo website, but allowing users to view the directory.
Then in SharePoint create a PageViewer web-app and apply the URL location to that folder/website. You may need to tinker with security permissions to allow it all to work.